# How to get multiple parameters from url as wildcard in laravel

Tags: php, parameters, request, wildcard, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to get multiple parameters from url and send them to view but what I get is undefined variable. how to fix this :

**api.php**

```
Route::get('adwidth/{width}/adheight/{height}/aduser/{user_id}', function(){
    return view('frame', compact('width','height','user_id'));
});
```

**frame.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
    <h3>{{ $width }}</h3>
@stop
```

I'm using laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution I had to pass those parameters to my closure like below :

```
Route::get('adwidth/{width}/adheight/{height}/aduser/{user_id}', function($width, $height, $user_id){
    return view('frame', compact('width','height','user_id'));
});
```

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030097/how-to-add-some-textfield-in-form-register-laravel-generator-infyom